# Bayesian Proportion Test ... with Cumulative Successes and Trials?

Tags: r, probability, bayesian, proportion, group-differences

I am conducting a Bayesian Proportions Test (using R's [BayesianFirstAid](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/01/bayesian-first-aid/) package) of consumer conversion rates at different ad impression frequencies.  Conversions are considered successes and impressions are considered trials.  This data might look like:

```
> head(x, 10)
   Freq   Conv        Imp
1     1 270900 1691270667
2     2 185090  492294876
3     3 119744  329414751
4     4  90498  261627880
5     5  62878  206159185
6     6  51916  180760428
7     7  38659  146174847
8     8  32890  131011008
9     9  26047  114761484
10   10  22570  105066150
```

Where a call to `bayes.prop.test` yields the following insight:

```
> (x_short <- bayes.prop.test(x$Conv[1:10], x$Imp[1:10], n.iter = 1000))

    Bayesian First Aid proportion test

data: x$Conv[1:10] out of x$Imp[1:10]
number of successes:      270900,     185090,     119744,      90498,      62878,      51916,      38659,      32890,      26047,      22570
number of trials:     1691270667,  492294876,  329414751,  261627880,  206159185,  180760428,  146174847,  131011008,  114761484,  105066150
Estimated relative frequency of success [95% credible interval]:
  Group 1: 0.00016 [0.00016, 0.00016]
  Group 2: 0.00038 [0.00037, 0.00038]
  Group 3: 0.00036 [0.00036, 0.00037]
  Group 4: 0.00035 [0.00034, 0.00035]
  Group 5: 0.00031 [3e-04, 0.00031]
  Group 6: 0.00029 [0.00028, 0.00029]
  Group 7: 0.00026 [0.00026, 0.00027]
  Group 8: 0.00025 [0.00025, 0.00025]
  Group 9: 0.00023 [0.00022, 0.00023]
  Group 10: 0.00021 [0.00021, 0.00022]
```

Leaving aside a discussion of these results, **my question pertains to whether or not it is appropriate to use a cumulative measure of these conversions and impressions, since the `Frequency 2` bin also saw the first round of ads, which are binned into `Frequency 1` and so on...**

This new data would look like...

```
> head(x_cumul, 10)
   Freq   Conv        Imp Cumul_Conv  Cumul_Imp
1     1 270900 1691270667     270900 1691270667
2     2 185090  492294876     455990 2183565543
3     3 119744  329414751     575734 2512980294
4     4  90498  261627880     666232 2774608174
5     5  62878  206159185     729110 2980767359
6     6  51916  180760428     781026 3161527787
7     7  38659  146174847     819685 3307702634
8     8  32890  131011008     852575 3438713642
9     9  26047  114761484     878622 3553475126
10   10  22570  105066150     901192 3658541276
```

And its associated `bayes.prop.test` yields instead these results, which show lower, relative probabilities of converting as you move up through frequency bins:

```
> (x_cumul_short <- bayes.prop.test(x_cumul$Cumul_Conv[1:10], x_cumul$Cumul_Imp[1:10], n.iter = 1000))

    Bayesian First Aid proportion test

data: x_cumul$Cumul_Conv[1:10] out of x_cumul$Cumul_Imp[1:10]
number of successes:      270900,     455990,     575734,     666232,     729110,     781026,     819685,     852575,     878622,     901192
number of trials:     1691270667, 2183565543, 2512980294, 2774608174, 2980767359, 3161527787, 3307702634, 3438713642, 3553475126, 3658541276
Estimated relative frequency of success [95% credible interval]:
  Group 1: 0.00016 [0.00016, 0.00016]
  Group 2: 0.00021 [0.00021, 0.00021]
  Group 3: 0.00023 [0.00023, 0.00023]
  Group 4: 0.00024 [0.00024, 0.00024]
  Group 5: 0.00024 [0.00024, 0.00025]
  Group 6: 0.00025 [0.00025, 0.00025]
  Group 7: 0.00025 [0.00025, 0.00025]
  Group 8: 0.00025 [0.00025, 0.00025]
  Group 9: 0.00025 [0.00025, 0.00025]
  Group 10: 0.00025 [0.00025, 0.00025]
```

Is there a "right" answer or - if not - which one is "more appropriate"?

Comment: I would say that the `bayes.prop.test` might be a bit simplistic in this case, and you would be able build a more reasonable model, given you data, using say Stan or Jags. However,  `bayes.prop.test` gives some sense of the uncertainties in the estimates, and since the credible intervals are so narrow, the estimated rates should be pretty accurate.

Comment: Thanks for writing this package and your blog, @RasmusBååth.  My colleague and I were concerned about the narrowness of those credible intervals; that they were too narrow to be of extra use (since they're essentially just the mean value).  Is there any reason to be concerned, or since it's just a function of the size of the trials live with it?

Comment: Also, @RasmusBååth, any opinion on the use of the cumulative?

Comment: Well, narrow intervals are good! That means you can can trust the point estimates much more. Even if you use the cumulative version or the other version, and even if the model you use is not a "perfect fit", both have so narrow credible intervals that I think you could focus more on the actual estimates, and what they mean for your busines decision! :)

Comment: @RasmusBååth good point :) Do you have any suggestions on bumping the (very) narrow margins out on the graphs so the values don't print on top of one another?

Comment: We'll, not using the built in plot which doesn't take any options... So I would, unfortunately, do a custom plot from scratch...

Comment: @RasmusBååth no worries - thanks for the knowledge!